# how to redirect to root file in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

My loging page in `root/Account/Login.aspx` page when I click on contact us i need to redirect to `root/contactus.aspx` page.
I used `Response.Redirect("~/contactus.aspx")` in Master page (Site.Master)

```
 Protected Sub lbContactUs_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbContactUs.Click
    Response.Redirect("~/contactus.aspx")

End Sub
```

Still it is not redirecting to page.

[image]

Comment: That should work, what error are you getting?

Comment: Are you sure you have the event wired up? That should work fine.

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking... Response.Redirect("~/contactus.aspx") works fine for redirecting to the ContactUs.aspx page. Do you get some error when you run this line of code?

Comment: its coming to event method. after that it is staying login.aspx page only. but url will be like this `http://localhost:60720/account/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fContactUS.aspx`

Comment: Ok, that means you have secured your ContactUs.aspx page. Check your web.config for items like <authorization><allow roles="Administrator" /><deny users="*" /></authorization> and allow access for anonymus users

Comment: I have this... <authorization>
      <deny users="?"  />
      <allow roles="client"/>
      <allow roles="admin"/>
      <allow roles="member"/>
      <allow roles="superadmin"/>
    </authorization>

Answer (score 6):

You are not redirecting properly.

```
Response.Redirect("/contactus.aspx", False);
Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Do not use `Response.Redirect(url)`. It calls `Response.End` **which is very taxing on the server**.

`Response.Redirect(url, false)` **is much faster and more efficient**.

`Response.End` will raise a `ThreadAbortException` which costs a lot for the server to do.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2009/06/25/correct-use-of-system-web-httpresponse-redirect.aspx

`@Jason Kulatunga`'s answer looks like it will solve your problem. The above information is just for good practice.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to your `web.config`

```
<configuration>
...
<location path="ContactUs.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
... 
</configuration>
```

It seems that you have a deny all anonymous users rule set in your `web.config`. If you need to allow anonymous users access to specific pages, while still leaving the rest of your site protected by forms authentication, you can use the `location` tag to override the security for specific pages.

Answer (score 1):

@James123: Use

```
 Protected Sub lbContactUs_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbContactUs.Click
 Response.Redirect("/contactus.aspx")
```

End Sub

this will redirect to root directory

Comment: Response.Redirect(url) is extremely expensive for the server. You should always the overloaded method that has the endResponse parameter, and set it to false. This will prevent a AbortThreatException.